# Does cursor.getString() coerce an int into a string?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

The docs say:

> The result and whether this method throws an exception when the
>   column value is null or the column type is not a string type is
>   implementation-defined.

Which implementation are they talking about? The version of sqlite? Will calling

```
cursor.getString(INT_COLUMN)
```

coerce the `int` value into a `String`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Does cursor.getString() coerce an int into a string?

Yes, the same data from your table can be returned with `getString()`, `getInt()`, `getLong()`, etc as long as it makes sense.  For example,

- If the column data is 42: `getInt()` returns 42 and `getString()` returns "42".
- If the column data is plant: `getString()` returns "plant", `getInt()` returns 0.